# How can I make keyword start at next line if there's not enough space to show whole keyword?

Tags: html, css

How can I make keyword start at next line if there's not enough space to show whole keyword?
Please check my code.

**I want this Output** : keyword should start at next line if there's not enough space to show whole.

```
Tags: Apple Banana Melon 
      Strawberry Kiwi Orange 
      Pineapple Carrot Onion 
      Tomato Bacon Sandwitch
      SoyBeans Pork Beef Chicken
```

**Current Output** : keyword is devided to current line and the head of next line.

```
Tags: Apple Banana Melon Strawbe
      rry Kiwi Orange Pineapple 
      Carrot Onion Tomato Bacon 
      Sandwitch SoyBeans Pork Be
      ef Chicken
```

**Current HTML**

```
<div class="shop_tag ">
    <table>
        <tr>
         <th class="tag_title">tags:</th>
         <th class="tag_tags">
          <ul>
                    <li>Apple</li>
                    <li>Banana</li>
                    <li>Melon</li>
                    <li>Strawberry</li>
                    <li>Kiwi</li>
                      ....
          </ul>
         </th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**Current CSS**

```
div.shop_tag .table{
    display:table-row;
    display:inline;
}
div.shop_tag th.tag_title{
    width:100px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
div.shop_tag th.tag_tags{
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align:left;
}  
div.shop_tag li{
display:inline;
}
```

**UPDATE:** At Firefox's inspector, these classes are inherited.

```
a:focus {
    outline: thin dotted rgb(51, 51, 51);
    outline-offset: -2px;
}

.css3 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: rgb(112, 165, 255);
}

a {
    color: rgb(0, 136, 204);
}

li {
    line-height: 20px;
}

div.shop_tag th.tag_tags {
    text-align: left;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Please make proper jsFiddle. Your provided code does not produce described output: http://jsfiddle.net/ZAtfZ/

Comment: I don't understand how the word can be broken without using css property `word-break`?

Comment: @Amberlamps Thanks for checking. I added another information. Is something preventing??

Comment: I have tested your code and have made a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/9dL9q/  The words don't break at the end of the line as expected. You must have somewhere in your css (perhaps inline) a rule that overrides the word-break.